# Javascript image comparison

Tags: javascript, css, html, web

```
    function reOrderImage()
    {
        var bilder = new Array();
        bilder[1] = "sne.jpg";
        bilder[2] = "banan.jpg";
        bilder[3] = "monkey.jpg";

        var img = document.getElementById('bild')
        var img2 = document.getElementById('bild2')
        var img3 = document.getElementById('bild3')

        img.src = bilder[getRandomInt()]
        img2.src = bilder[getRandomInt()]
        img3.src = bilder[getRandomInt()]

        if(img.src == bilder[2] && img2.src == bilder[2] && img3.src == bilder[2])
        {
            alert("JACKPOOOOT MON!");
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to compare if 3 images are the same, if they are equal to the bilder[2] it should alert out jackpot!

Comment: Its only a typo, I'm sorry I'll upload the script as it should be. It still dosen't work.

Comment: Oh, and `image.src` returns an absolute URL, it will never be equal to `sne.jpg` as it's more like `http://www.mysite.com/bilder/sne.jpg` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is store the values you use as source url in a variable:

```
var url, url2, url3;
img.src = url = bilder[getRandomInt()]
img2.src = url2 = bilder[getRandomInt()]
img3.src = url3 = bilder[getRandomInt()]

if (url == bilder[2] && url2 == bilder[2] && url3 == bilder[2]) {}
```

That will prevent the urls from being retrieved as absolute urls from the images.

#### Original answer:

Compare the three urls first, and then see if they are equal to the part after the last slash in the absolute url:

```
if (img.src == img2.src && img2.src == img3.src && img.src.split('/').pop() == bilder[2]) {}
```